# How to use C# methods in a PS script and pass PS variables as arguments to the method?

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

I'm working in a custom environment where I'm writing Powershell scripts as well as using C# methods.
I need help figuring out the best way to pass PS arguments to the C# method, where the value inside the variable is what is sent, not just the name of the variable.
Example:

```
$en = "en"
$to = "to"
$call = "success({0},{1})" -f $en, $to
```

C# methdod success(string input, string input2) is a method that expects two arguments.
However, no matter what I do, the values inside $en and $to is not what gets sent to the method, it sends {0} and {1}, or if I try:

`success($en,$to)`

or

`"success($en, $to)"`

it gets $en and $to, not the values inside those variables.

Any smart way to solve this?

For example if I use $en and $to as arguments, I want to send the value inside those variables to the C# method, not just "$en" and "$to" which is what is happening now.

I also tried using -f command to use {0} and {1} but then it just gets exactly {0} and {1}.

Comment: You need to explain better what you are doing when you say passing variable to a c# method.  If the c# methods are in a main method you are passing arguments to compiled executable.  If you are using standard c# methods than you are passing variables on the execution stack.  c# like standard c language pushes parameters on the stack in reverse order.

Comment: Understand what your script is doing first. You have 3 variables and are assigning string values to them. The `-f` is an operator for formatting a string value. You haven't shown any c# code, and you are not executing c#/.net code anywhere. If you want to "run" c# code, research `Add-Type -TypeDefinition`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While **PowerShell does allow you to use *expressions* in member accesses** (method calls and property accesses using regular *dot notation*), such expressions **must evaluate to the *name* of the member only - nothing else**.

- That is, in your case the resulting string must not include the *arguments* to pass to the method.

The following sample code demonstrates two **solutions**, based on calling [`[datetime]::Parse()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTime.Parse) via the method name and arguments specified via variables:

```bash
# Define the method name in a variable.
$methodName = 'Parse'

# Define the arguments.
$dateStr = "1.10.2024"
$culture = [cultureinfo] 'fr-FR'

# OPTION 1:
# Invoke with individually enumerated arguments.
[datetime]::$methodName($dateStr, $culture)

# OPTION 2:
# Invocation via an *array* of arguments.
$params = @($dateStr, $culture)
[datetime]::$methodName.Invoke($params)
```

Note:

- `[datetime]::Parse()` happens to be a *static method*, which is why **`::`** - the [static member(-access) operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#static-member-operator-) - must be used to call it, but the above equally applies to *instance* members, which are accessed with **`.`** - the (instance) [member-access operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#member-access-operator-).